# Search and extract element located in various path of json structure

Tags: jsonb, postgresql-12

I have a json in a PostgreSQL database and I need to extract an array not always located in same place.

> Problem

- Need to extract array `choicies` of a particular element `name`
- Element `name` is known, but not where he's sitting in structure

> Rules

- All elements `name` are unique
- `choicies` attribute could not be present

> JSON structure

```
pages : [
  {
    name : 'page1',
    elements : [
      { name : 'element1', choicies : [...]},
      { name : 'element2', choicies : [...]}
    ]
  }, {
    name : 'page2',
    elements : [
      {
        name : 'element3',
        templateElements : [
          {
            name : 'element4'
            choicies : [...]
          }, {                  
            name : 'element5'
            choicies : [...]
          }
       ]
      }, {
        name : 'element6'
        choicies : [...]
      }
    ]
  },{
    name : 'element7',
    templateElements : [
      {
        name : 'element8'
        choicies : [...]
      }
    ]
  }         
]
```

**My try to extract elements by flatten the structure**

```
SELECT  pages::jsonb->>'name',
        pageElements::jsonb ->> 'name',
        pageElements::jsonb -> 'choicies',
        pages.*
FROM    myTable as myt,
        jsonb_array_elements(myt.json -> 'pages') as pages,
        jsonb_array_elements(pages -> 'elements') as pageElements
```

Alas column `choicies` is always null in my results. And that will not work when element is located somewhere else, like

- page.elements.templateElements
- page.templateElements
- ... and so on

I don't know if there is a way to search for a key (name) wherever it's sitting in json structure and extract an other key (choicies).

I wish to call a select with element name in parameter return choicies of this element.

By instance, if I call select with element name (element1 or element4 or element8), choicies array (as rows or json or text, no preference here) of this element should be return.

Comment: What exactly is the output you want?

Comment: P.S.: it would be easier for us if you posted valid JSON, so that we can just copy and paste it to test a possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow! Solution founded goes beyond expectation! **JSONPath** was the way to go

Amazing what we can do with this.

> **SQL**

```
-- Use jsonpath to search, filter and return what's needed
SELECT  jsonb_path_query(
            myt.jsonb,
            '$.** ? (@.name == "element_name_to_look_at")'
        )->'choices' as jsonbChoices
FROM    myTable as myt
```

> **Explanation of jsonpath in SQL**

```
jsonb_path_query(jsonb_data, '$.** ? (@.name == "element_name_to_look_at")')->'choices'
```

- `jsonb_path_query` : posgresql jsonpath function
- `jsonb_data` : database column with jsonb data or jsonb expression
- `$.**` : search everywhere from root element
- `?` : where clause / filter
- `@` : object return by search
- `@.name == "element_name_to_look_at"` : every object `name` equals `element_name_to_look_at`
- `->'choices'` : for each object returned by jsonpath, get `choices` attribute

> **Final version**

After get `choices` jsonb array, we return a dataset with every choice.

`choices` arrays look like this :

`[{value:'code1',text:'Code Label 1'}, {value:'code2',text:'Code Label 2'},...]`

```
SELECT  choices.*
FROM    (
        -- Use jsonpath to search, filter and return what's needed
        SELECT  jsonb_path_query(myt.jsonb, '$.** ? (@.name == "element_name_to_look_at")')->'choices' as jsonbChoices
        FROM    myTable as myt
) choice,
-- Explode json return array into columns
jsonb_to_recordset(choice.jsonbChoices) as choices(value text, text text);
```